# Visualforce form, hide or show checkbox depending on the picklist

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist, form, checkbox

I created a form and I want to show the checkbox option depending on the value in the picklist. Let's say if the user chooses "Apples" in the picklist, the checkbox shows, if he choooses "Oranges" the checkbox stays hidden. How would I do this?

I am new to this whole platform and apex in general, please be kind and thank you for you answers.

Code:

```
<apex:page StandardController="tudent__c">
<apex:form >

    <apex:pageBlock title="Prijava Študenta">


    <apex:actionRegion >   
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="formToRerender">

        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="formToRerender"/>

        <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.Name }"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.Priimek__c }"/>        
        <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.Naslov__c }"/>        
        <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.Datum_Rojstva__c }"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.Letnik__c }"/>   
        <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.Studijski_program__c }"/> 
        <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.Samopla_niki__c }" rendered="{!tudent__c.Studijski_program__c='Izredni'}"/>  

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:actionRegion>   


    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton action="{! save }" value="Save" />        
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>

</apex:pageBlock>

     <apex:pageBlock title="Študenti">

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!tudent__c}" var="contact">



    <apex:column value="{!contact.Name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!contact.Priimek__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!contact.Naslov__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!contact.Datum_rojstva__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!contact.Studijski_program__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!contact.Samopla_niki__c}"/>


</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>



</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Your table is using a single sObject. What is the purpose since you show the information in the pageblock section. Either way use the render attribute and the value bound to the picklist. Rerender table on change of picklist

Comment: Yes and you use the value the picklist is bound to

Comment: See answer here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140671/displaying-fields-based-on-picklist-apexselectoption/140673#140673

Comment: What's going on with your questions, why are you _censoring_ them?

Comment: For some reason it won't let me change my email so I wanted to delete my account and make a new one. I'm sorry for the confusion, I contacted the help center.

Comment: Can a mod please restore the question and comments like they were? And again, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below you can see a simple example that doesn't require the use of custom controller or controller extensions, so you can keep using just your `standardController` as you already are. You should be able to implement a similar logic for your page.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" >  
    <apex:form >
         <apex:pageBlock title="New Account" >

             <apex:actionRegion> 
                 <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbToRerender">                
                        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Type}" >
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"                             
                                                rerender="pbToRerender"/>
                        </apex:inputField>    
                        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.AccountNumber}" rendered="{!Account.Type='Prospect'}">
                        </apex:inputField>          
                 </apex:pageBlockSection>
             </apex:actionRegion>

             <apex:pageBlockSection >
                 <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}"></apex:inputField>
             </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Basically, when you change the `Account.Type` the `onchange` event will be triggered, causing the re-rendering of the `pageBlockSection`. The `actionRegion` tag will make sure that only this limited part of the page is submitted and processed on the server. In the example above it allows the user to change the picklist without the need to input the `Account.Name`, which is a required field.

However, if you want to do this "client-side" only, you can use JQuery to show/hide your checkbox when the picklist changes.

Comment: Update your code above please, so we can see what code you have now.

Comment: See my example code again, the `actionSupport` needs to be between the `inputField` tags so it gets triggered when that `inputField` changes. Try like this: `<apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.Studijski_program__c }"> <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="formToRerender"/></apex:inputField>`

Comment: It's not that hard, you'll get a hang of it in a few weeks, I'm sure. BTW, just curious, what's the language that you are using in your form? It looks very similar to Serbian, but not quite the same :)

Comment: I think you should ask a separate questions for this new problem you are facing so that you can get a detailed answer. However, this might get you started: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_about.htm